# Example usage of marks as provided in ltmarks.dtx

Tags: output

The `ltmarks.dtx` provides a number of design level as well as code level commands, such as `\FirstMark`, `\BottomMark`, `\LastMark`. Can someone provide a short example of their usage with explanations? It also later on provides "classes", i.e., names for marks for certain page regions and talks about "galley". Are these already usable. Is the "galley" concept integrated in the output routine?

Looking for a MWE demonstrating their canonical use in a package or author code.